# Authentication login-modules flag sufficient does not work with two modules but works individually

Tags: security, authentication, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly

If I test them individually work well but when I put it together the neither Database module nor Ldap module can authenticate properly.

What am I missing?

**standalone.xml**

```
...
<authentication>
    <login-module code="LdapExtended" flag="sufficient">
        <module-option name="java.naming.factory.initial" value="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"/>
        <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url" value="ldap://ldap.domain.net:389"/>
        <module-option name="java.naming.security.authentication" value="simple"/>
        <module-option name="baseCtxDN" value="dc=domain,dc=global"/>
        <module-option name="baseFilter" value="(&amp;(uid={0})(memberOf=cn=rol,ou=Rols,ou=Groups,dc=rol,dc=global))"/>
        <module-option name="rolesCtxDN" value="ou=Rols,ou=Groups,dc=rol,dc=global"/>
        <module-option name="roleFilter" value="(member=uid={1},ou=Users,dc=rol,dc=global)"/>
        <module-option name="roleAttributeID" value="cn"/>
        <module-option name="roleAttributeIsDN" value="false"/>
        <module-option name="searchScope" value="SUBTREE_SCOPE"/>
        <module-option name="allowEmptyPasswords" value="true"/>
    </login-module>
    <login-module code="Database" flag="sufficient">
        <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS"/>
        <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="SELECT password FROM t_user WHERE username = ?"/>
        <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="SELECT none, 'Roles' FROM t_user WHERE username = ?"/>
    </login-module>
</authentication>
...
```

**web.xml**

```
...
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>myrealm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/login-error.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
...
```

And a form that calls to j_security_check as default with j_username and j_password.

Comment: I've test with the property <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/> in each module but it is still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with the roles query, it provokes an error and all the modules stop working.
The same error occurs when the query return no values.

```
<module-option name="rolesQuery" value="SELECT none, 'Roles' FROM t_user WHERE username = ?"/>
```

none should go in between apostrophes('') because its not a field of the table.